# Failed to start Instruments daemon on ‘P_v_iphone_5s (7.1.2)’ (The service is invalid.)

Tags: ios, appium, inspector

1. I am using Xcode Version 6.3.2 and appium version 1.3.7.
2. I am getting below defined error message, When I start appium server

> Launching Appium with command:
>   '/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node'
>   lib/server/main.js --command-timeout "7200" --pre-launch
>   --platform-version "7.1.2" --platform-name "iOS" --app "com.company.iphone.sampleApp" --udid
>   "1c71d40a38f94c9e6682f5409e6ea6c0ec081736" --show-ios-log
>   --device-name "iPhone 5s" --isolate-sim-device
>
> info: [debug] Starting Appium in pre-launch mode
>
> info: Pre-launching app info: [debug] App is an iOS bundle, will
>   attempt to run as pre-existing
>
> info: [debug] Creating new appium session
>   cb824b1c-461e-41c1-9f34-2746150b37af info: [debug] Removing any
>   remaining instruments sockets
>
> info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
>   info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
>
> info: [debug] Setting Xcode version
>
> info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
>
> info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout
>
> info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.3
>
> info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're
>   on a real device info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
>
> info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
>
> info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at
>   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/company.iphone.sampleApp/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
>
> info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML info: [debug] Could not
>   parse plist file (as XML) at
>   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/company.iphone.sampleApp/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
>   warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings assuming it doesn't
>   exist info: [debug] Creating instruments
>
> info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not
>   work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the
>   --native-instruments-lib flag info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/alk/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap info: [debug] Dynamic env:
>   {"nodePath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false,"autoDismissAlerts":false,"sendKeyStrategy":"grouped"}
>
> info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically
>   generated. Do not manually modify! ... info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap
>   path: /Users/alk/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js
>
> info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap:
>   /Users/alk/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js info: [debug]
>   Getting device string from opts:
>   {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.3.2","iOSSDKVersion":"8.3","deviceName":"iPhone
>   5s","platformVersion":"7.1.2"} info: [debug] fixDevice is on info:
>   [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 5s (7.1.2 Simulator)' info:
>   [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device info:
>   [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences info: [debug]
>   Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device info:
>   [debug] Running ios sim reset flow info: [debug] Killing the simulator
>   process info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator info: [debug] Killing any
>   other simulator daemons
>
> info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
>
> info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
>   info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set info: [debug] Starting
>   iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
>
> info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator
>
> info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid
>   1c71d40a38f94c9e6682f5409e6ea6c0ec081736 info: [debug] Checking app
>   install status using:
>   /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap
>   isInstalled --id 1c71d40a38f94c9e6682f5409e6ea6c0ec081736 --bundle
>   com.company.iphone.sampleApp
>
> info: [debug] App is installed.
>
> info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install. info:
>   [debug] Starting command proxy.
>
> info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at
>   /tmp/instruments_sock info: [debug] Starting instruments info: [debug]
>   Instruments is at:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments info:
>   Launching instruments info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real
>   device with UDID 1c71d40a38f94c9e6682f5409e6ea6c0ec081736 info:
>   [debug] Spawning instruments with command:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate
>   -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 1c71d40a38f94c9e6682f5409e6ea6c0ec081736 company.iphone.sampleApp -e
>   UIASCRIPT "/Users/alk/Library/Application
>   Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-d5a0fb924946d8d3.js" -e
>   UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments info: [debug] And extra
>   without-delay env: {} info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms):
>   {"global":90000}
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:11 P-v-iphone-5s
>   mobile_installation_proxy[127] : 0x1004ac000 handle_connection: Could
>   not receive request from host.
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:11 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   01cdc000 -[hostWatcher initWithCheckinGoop:]: created
>   [F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358 fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:23005]
>   [fd=17] info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:11 P-v-iphone-5s
>   lockdownd[25] : 01cdc000 -[hostWatcher initWithCheckinGoop:]:
>   replacing old hostWatcher for F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358:
>   [F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358 fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:17629]
>   [fd=13] info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:11 P-v-iphone-5s
>   lockdownd[25] : 01cdc000 -[hostWatcher invalidate]: invalidating host
>   F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358 info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29
>   16:57:11 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] : 01d64000 _25-[hostWatcher
>   invalidate]block_invoke: watcher for
>   F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358 has already been replaced by
>   [F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358 fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:23005]
>   [fd=17]
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:11 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   01d64000 -[hostWatcher dealloc]: dealloc
>   [F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358 fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:17629]
>   [fd=13] info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s
>   locationd[60] : NStatManagerHandleSrcCounts:1717 couldn't find
>   NStatSourceRef for 629 info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12
>   P-v-iphone-5s locationd[60] : NStatManagerHandleSrcDescriptor:1263
>   update descriptor for invalid source info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29
>   16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] : 01f84000 -[watchedServiceInfo
>   logService:]: first service [client=deviceconsole
>   (F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358 fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:25309)]
>   [fd=22] [pid=137 (syslog_relay fd=21)] [hb=14018437927] info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   01f84000 -[watchedServiceInfo logService:]: Watching
>   [client=deviceconsole (F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358
>   fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:25309)] [fd=22] [pid=137 (syslog_relay fd=21)]
>   [hb=14018437927] info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-05-29 16:57:09.460
>   instruments[4584:88508] Failed to start Instruments daemon on
>   'P_v_iphone_5s (7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.) info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   021a4000 -[hostWatcher runWatcher]: starting loop for
>   [F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358 fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:23005]
>   [fd=17] info: [debug] [INST] Waiting for device to boot... info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   02094000 -[watchedServiceInfo logService:]: Watching
>   [client=deviceconsole (F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358
>   fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:25565)] [fd=12] [pid=137 (syslog_relay fd=26)]
>   [hb=14019322067]
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   01bcc000 -[watchedServiceInfo logService:]: Watching
>   [client=deviceconsole (F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358
>   fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:25821)] [fd=23] [pid=137 (syslog_relay fd=29)]
>   [hb=14019420444] info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s
>   lockdownd[25] : 0200c000 -[watchedServiceInfo logService:]: Watching
>   [client=deviceconsole (F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358
>   fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:26077)] [fd=24] [pid=137 (syslog_relay fd=30)]
>   [hb=14019682524] info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s
>   lockdownd[25] : 02094000 -[watchedServiceInfo logService:]: Watching
>   [client=deviceconsole (F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358
>   fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:26333)] [fd=25] [pid=137 (syslog_relay fd=31)]
>   [hb=14019845299] info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s
>   lockdownd[25] : 02094000 -[watchedServiceInfo logService:]: Watching
>   [client=deviceconsole (F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358
>   fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:26589)] [fd=26] [pid=137 (syslog_relay fd=32)]
>   [hb=14019858305] info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s
>   lockdownd[25] : 0200c000 -[watchedServiceInfo logService:]: Watching
>   [client=deviceconsole (F0FE931A-0099-4F10-932A-FAE4065DF358
>   fe80::6e40:8ff:fea6:b9a:26845)] [fd=27] [pid=137 (syslog_relay fd=33)]
>   [hb=14020003369] info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s
>   lockdownd[25] : 01efc000 spawn_service_agent: Could not look up
>   service in the map info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12
>   P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] : 01efc000 spawn_and_handle_checkin: Could
>   not spawn the com.apple.instruments.remoteserver service
>   agent:InvalidService info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12
>   P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] : 01efc000 spawn_service_agent: Could not
>   look up service in the map info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12
>   P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] : 01efc000 spawn_and_handle_checkin: Could
>   not spawn the com.apple.instruments.server service
>   agent:InvalidService
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   0200c000 set_response_error: handle_start_session SessionActive
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   0200c000 spawn_service_agent: Could not look up service in the map
>
> info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2015-05-29 16:57:09.564
>   instruments[4584:88502] Failed to start Instruments daemon on
>   'P_v_iphone_5s (7.1.2)' (The service is invalid.)
>
> info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   0200c000 spawn_and_handle_checkin: Could not spawn the
>   com.apple.instruments.remoteserver service agent:InvalidService info:
>   [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   0200c000 spawn_service_agent: Could not look up service in the map
>   info: [IOS_SYSLOG_ROW ] May 29 16:57:12 P-v-iphone-5s lockdownd[25] :
>   0200c000 spawn_and_handle_checkin: Could not spawn the
>   com.apple.instruments.server service agent:InvalidService